# HTML anchor tags are overlapping

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and I am attempting to make a twitter clone using Ruby and HTML. I was wondering why my anchor is overlapping in my class="tag". If you look closely, you can see overlap to the far right below Tags section. Another issue I am having is that I would like my buttons aligned horizontally, i.e. "delete", "edit", "add comment" and "add tag". To be more clear I have added a photo at. Any advice would be a huge help!

Here is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Chitter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mainstyle.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
<body>
  <main>
<section class="glass">
  <div class="dashboard">
<% if @user %>
   <h1>Welcome, <%= @user.email %></h1>
   <form action="/sessions/destroy" method="post">
     <input type="submit" value="Sign out" />
   </form>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 <ul class="tweets">
   <form class="tweet_text" action="/tweet" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="url" placeholder="Whats happening?" id="text" />
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
   </form>
   <% @chitter.each do |tweets| %>
    <li class="tweet"<%= tweets.id %>>
          <%= tweets.url %>
      <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'/>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
      </form>
      <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/edit" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
      </form>
      <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/comments/new" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
      </form>
      <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/tags/new" method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" />
      </form>
      <% if tweets.tags.length > 0 %>
      <div class="tag">
          <h2>Tags</h2>
          <ul>
            <% tweets.tags.each do |tag| %>
              <li>
                <a href="/tags/<%= tag.id %>/tweet">
                  <%= tag.content %>
                </a>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
main {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right top, #65dfc9, #6cdbeb);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.glass {
  background: white;
  min-height: 90vh;
  width: 90%;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
  );
  border-radius: 2rem;
  z-index: 2;
  backdrop-filter: blur(2rem);
  display: flex;
}

.dashboard {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
  );
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.tweets {
  flex: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.tweet_text {
  background: linear-gradient(
  to right bottom,
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
);
  width: 40%;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.tweet {
  margin: 2rem 0rem;
}

.tag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  right: 2rem;
  height: 8rem;
  width: 8rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
  );
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try inspecting the links and seeing if they've inheritted `position: absolute` from the .tag div.

Comment: I need to do a little research on how to use inspect effectively, not quite sure if I understand anything that was causing the problem when inspecting. At least it gives me something to explore some more. Cheers ben!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would try it by adding a div container around your buttons and set it to `display: flex;` and for the tags try `display: flex;` and `flex-flow: column;`. And set `height: auto;` for the tags background.

Here are the CSS and HTML I used.

```css
  /*add display: flex; and height: auto;*/
  
  .tag {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    top: 3rem;
    right: 2rem;
    height: auto;
    width: 8rem;
    background: linear-gradient(
      to right bottom,
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7),
      rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)
    );
    border-radius: 1rem;
  }

  /*Flex container around form*/
  .flex-container-form {
      display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-form">
                        <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>" method="post">
                            <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE' />
                            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                        <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/edit" method="get">
                            <input type="submit" value="Edit" />
                        </form>
                        <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/comments/new" method="get">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
                        </form>
                        <form class="button" action="/tweet/<%= tweets.id %>/tags/new" method="get">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add Tag" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

I hope it helped a bit. ^^'

Comment: Glad to hear that I could help. ^^'